# How to make a position: fixed not move when the user is scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Alright, i have been looking to use pixel coordinates for my div's and i recently found a bug on my webpage. Basically, when you scroll the div's follows. The div's i currently have all have a position of static, so i can assign them coordinates.

```
    $("#assistance").css({
        top: "427.4375px",
        left: "5px"
    });
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you position elements you do not need to position divs with position fixed. You can assign divs with coordinates using position absolute and they will not follow as you scroll.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS position property.

```
    position:fixed;
```